# Why is the following piece of code running considerably slower in a WCF service vs console application?

Tags: c#, performance, wcf, garbage-collection

I have the following piece of code. It allocates a big list and then call `ToList()` on it :

```
//allocate 10.000.000 references to hold objects
List<object> list = new List<object>(10000000);
for (int i = 0; i < 10000000; i++)
{
    list.Add(null);
}

while (true)
{
    Stopwatch sw = Stopwatch.StartNew();
    list.ToList();
    sw.Stop();
    Console.WriteLine(sw.Elapsed);
}
```

In a console application, release configuration, I got the following timings :

```
00:00:00.0389353
00:00:00.0385094
      ...        //skipped 10 similar lines
00:00:00.0387278
00:00:00.0386860
00:00:00.1450610 <- gc ?
00:00:00.0442339
00:00:00.0383709
      ...        //skipped 10 similar lines
00:00:00.0442156
00:00:00.0391734
00:00:00.1718344 <- gc ?
00:00:00.0451683
```

If I compile in debug mode and debugger attached, it gives similar timings.

However if I ran exact same code in a `WCF service` method (with exception of `Console.WriteLine()` call being replaced to return a response and the while loop being a for that loop from 0 to 99) I got the following :

```
00:00:00.0438848
00:00:00.0434771
00:00:00.0426696
00:00:00.0439244
00:00:01.3208667 <- gc ?
00:00:00.0452654
00:00:00.0426104
00:00:00.0428292
00:00:00.0435619
00:00:00.0430364
00:00:00.0434371
00:00:00.0433007
00:00:01.1786231 <- gc ?
00:00:00.0459642
00:00:00.0455757
00:00:00.0404102
00:00:00.0417411
```

Not only the garbage collector fire more often, but also it takes now roughly more than one second to clean up the allocations (which are basically big arrays) :(

I suspect the WCF service to use a different garbage collector than the console application (that might perform better in some cases but clearly not here. Anyway in this case this is a HUGE difference and it seems something is wrong.

Notes :

- This is on exact same CPU, same OS (Windows 8), same session. WCF Service ran as "Local IIS Web server" in VS2010 project settings. IIS8 is used.
- I make sure the WCF service was running without debugger attached and compiled with the following line in web.config :

  ```
  <compilation debug="false" targetFramework="4.5"/>
  ```

I am not sure if it is really effective. Shouldn't the `list.ToList()` call be removed by compiler after optimization ?

- I have try to change the gc configuration by adding the following settings in web.config :

  ```
  <configuration>
      <runtime>
          <gcConcurrent enabled="false"/>
          <gcServer enabled="false"/>
      </runtime>
  </configuration>
  ```

I have tried to put both on false, one and false and the other on true and the opposite (since AFAIK they are exclusive). It seems to have no effect.

- Both console application and IIS service process are running 64 bit (I checked in task manager)

**Here is my question : why is the code running slower and what can I do to improve the performance ?**

Comment: I assume your true app has a reason to do list.ToList(). In this example it makes no sense to convert a list to another list, which of course is the reason for the GC delays.

Comment: Other services in same IIS? Memory config of IIS?

Comment: @DrKoch the "true app" is actually performing some filtering / sorting which require array allocations. I ran into some performance issues, profiled code, removing pieces one by one until finding array allocation was the real problem. The only purpose of code in OP is to reproduce the behavior of this.

Comment: "Other services in same IIS?" > No. 
"Memory config of IIS?" > Not sure what you mean, can you elaborate a little bit about this ? Do you mean what is "advance settings" of the application pool ?

Comment: 1.3 seconds to clean up about 10 arrays of 10M null references sounds extremely excessive. The cleanup should cost about zero. The only GC cost is the traversal which should happen at memcpy speeds. One array copy takes 40ms (according to your benchmark). So a GC time of 135ms sounds about right because that's ~13.5ms per array traversed. What else could be going on except GC?

Comment: Do an experiement: Add GC.Collect() to the loop body. The times should now be stable. What's the average time in both environments?

Answer (score 1):

OK, I found the reason of this main difference. Basically I forget one detail (my fault). I post it here because it could be useful for someone else running into same trouble.

When performing the benchmark tests, the WCF service I tested (which is a real app, no a dummy empty service) has already allocated a lot of memory (mainly for DB caching). In total 4GB where in use by the IIS process. I forget about this because it is done automatically (one time only) at WCF service start, before calling any WCF method. Even if I recycle / recompile it fires automatically.

When running the service without these initial allocations (so very low memory usage before running tests), timings and memory usage are similar to console app (about 700MB used and 0.15 seconds for GC)

Possible explanation (as best as I know) :

There is no memory thrashing of what so ever, because there is plenty of RAM left on the 16GB machine I use and ToList() tests just need only a few hundreds MB

Anyway: the fact the service memory usage is already quite high, probably cause the garbage collector to fire more often, and the garbage collection process itself to be a lot more complex (there is lot small of objects allocated (due to DB caching) to be checked by GC each time, complex object graph, probably fragmentation etc...

@usr : the GC.Collect() call make effectively the timings more stable (but there is still some freezes of approx 0.40 seconds each time, so higher than the console app).

Comment: A G2 traverses all objects. This is the explanation. I have seen collection rates of 1-2GB/sec which fits.